# Saving downloaded data to csv doesn't add the extension .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I use this line to save my downloaded data to csv files, everything goes well but the saved file doesn't have the can extension at the end...

```
# Save data to CSV file
REN.to_csv('REN_USD_Binance_30m_'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")), 
           date_format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'+'.csv')
```

So this command will create this file **REN_USD_Binance_30m_2020-07-28** instead of **REN_USD_Binance_30m_2020-07-28.csv**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name you are providing is incorrect. You are providing csv to the date_format variable, not to the name.

I cannot comment on the REN.to_csv() as I do not know what REN is, nor what methods it has.

The first argument that you are passing is:

```
'REN_USD_Binance_30m_'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

In python3 that will show as:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> 'REN_USD_Binance_30m_'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
'REN_USD_Binance_30m_2020-07-28'
```

What you want:

```
>>> 'REN_USD_Binance_30m_'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + '.csv'
'REN_USD_Binance_30m_2020-07-28.csv'
```

So if the function you are calling is correct and date_format is a valid optional argument then to have the csv extension you would do:

```
# Save data to CSV file
REN.to_csv('REN_USD_Binance_30m_'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))+'.csv', 
           date_format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Or with .format, which is cleaner in my opinion:

```
REN.to_csv('REN_USD_Binance_30m_{}.csv'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")), date_format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

- For [`pandas.DataFrame.csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv), `path_or_buf` is the first parameter, so `.csv` in the incorrect location.
- Use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) to add the date to the filename.

  - `f'REN_USD_Binance_30m_{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}.csv'` can be used, but the code below is cleaner.
  - The date you're adding is already a `str` type, so it doesn't need `str()`.
  - With f-strings, there's no need to convert an object to a `str`.
- I would only import the `datetime` methods that need to be used.

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
REN.to_csv(f'REN_USD_Binance_30m_{dt}.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```